# DynamoDb throttling write requests even though DB is under provisioned capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In the dynamodb table, we are getting lot of throttled write requests at the rate of ~2500/min. I am having confusions in some of the things here:

1. The consumed write capacity is much lower than the provisioned write capacity. Eg. Consumed Write capacity = 500 and Provisioned Write Capacity = 800. Then also, why the throttling is happening?
2. There is another metric called Throttle write events which is like 100/min. What does this mean and how its different from throttle write requests?
3. The parameters in capacity I see to change are Target utilization, Minimum provisioned capacity and Maximum provisioned capacity for Write. They all look good to me. I am using Auto scaling. So, I am not sure, what is to increase which can fix this issue?
4. What is happening to the throttled write events? Will they result in exception in code?

Comment: Does the affected table has Global Secondary Indexes?

Comment: And if it does have GSIs, what is the provisioned capacity on the GSIs? If too low, throttling can happen.

Comment: It does have 2 GSIs but their write capacity is 800 and 1600 respectively. So, shouldn't those be okay?

Comment: What's the size of the items you write?

Comment: And also: How do the primary keys of your items look like?

Comment: Size of each item would be around 1 KB. I noticed one thing though. One of the Index that has provisioned capacity of 1600 is getting lot of throttling at around 30K to 40K. Not sure why its happening. Its consumed capacity is showing around 1000.

Comment: Primary key is combination of 2 fields which is just one row in dynamodb

Comment: But we are doing a batch save to dynamodb in which the number of rows can be upto 100. So, around 100Kb.

Comment: My current guess is that you have a hot partition somewhere. Maybe the parition key of one of your GSIs isn't distributed evenly?

Comment: What do you mean by partition key of GSI? Where can I see that in aws console?

Comment: Also, is there a way I can change the write capacity of the GSI? The provisioned capacity of indexes is showed as greyed.

Comment: Each GSI requires you to define one attribute as partition key: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html#GSI.OnlineOps.Creating I that key isn't evenly distributed you might get hot paritions. Similarly you might get hot partitions for the table itself, if its primary key isn't distributed evenly. That would affect the throughput you can reach negatively.

Comment: As for the provisioned capacity: That sounds like you have DynamoDB Auto Scaling enabled on that table. You could disable that and set it manually. If cost doesn't matter much and you don't want to worry about setting provisioned capacity, you could also switch to DynamoDB On-Demand. That wouldn't solve your possible hot partition problem though.

Answer (score 1):

How much do the partition keys vary when you write your data?

I previously ran into a similar issue, when inserting a lot of data for the same partition key in many consecutive BatchWriteItem calls. The problem there was that there were too many write requests for the same partition key - overwhelming the partitions -  which caused the throttling.

The solution is to structure the data in a BatchWriteItem call in such a way, that the partition keys are not repeating as much.

Comment: I believe some (not so long) time ago the DynamoDB was updated that when having hot partitions the key distribution will not be uniform (there is some math behind), but will allow higher throughput for hot partitions (mentioned at a reInvent event, but I cannot find it back). Anyway I'd agree to check the key distribution in this case

Comment: it was pretty recent that I ran into this